# How do I display content from another website that requires the user being logged in?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, authentication

Say I have a website that requires a login, hosted somewhere remote. I would like to make a portal that shows this remote site but should always be logged in with the same user name and password on this remote site. If possible the portal should ask for a username and password and then use an iframe ( or something similar now that they are being phased out)
to display this remote site where you shoudl be logged in.

I would like to know if there is a web-ap for something like this, if not whether this would be possible to create.

I do have access to a VPS running centos 64bit and a managed host.

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question; an iframe is designed to do exactly what you describe! Are you asking, ["what is an alternative to an iframe?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102878/better-alternative-to-an-iframe) instead?

Comment: an iframe will not save the username and password for the remote website, if I access it from two different locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [OpenID](http://openid.net/)?

Comment: Not exactly, the remote site is not hosted by me, but i want friends to be able to access it with my account and add content to it without sharing the password, I am running features on my site that tightly integrates with the content of this other site so I want to centralize access

Comment: If you are not a developer for the other site then you can't use their login information in your site. Browsers don't allow you to access another site's cookies for obvious security reasons. So unless you are the developer of the other site there is no way to integrate both sites together behind a single login.

Comment: no I don't want to integrate their site login. Imagine like I have a google web email account, and I have a website of my own what I want is to have something like an iframe that loads this email account already logged in. However an iframe will not allow every user that access the site to have that account logged in already

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't possible if you don't have control over the other site.

Comment: ok, so not even with something proxy-like?

Comment: A proxy would be no different then using an iframe.

Comment: ok thanx dude i'll select this as best answer then, although i believe with alot of work it would be possible. all websites store login details somewhere locally if you select "remember me" and the like, as a proxy is supposed to access the website on your behalf why can it not log in on your behalf as well.